# Generated images showing flipped

Tags: image, image-processing, tiff

We have a image, but it's showing flipped on Google Chrome, Safari, iOS and iPhone. 
But image showing correctly on IE and Android.

How it could be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The image is shown rotated because it contains an Exif Orientation field which is set to "Rotate 90 CW" (value 6). This could happen if the image was rotated in software that don't also update the Exif data. Chrome, Safari et al is honoring this field, while the software that shows the image "correctly" doesn't.

According to the Exif fields, it's the rotated version that is correct.

To show correctly in all software, remove the Exif Orientation field.

See [TIFF Orientation](http://www.awaresystems.be/imaging/tiff/tifftags/orientation.html) for more info.